# How to create custom middleware in express?

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I need custom middle ware in express with routes with promise to perform specific task. Below is the sample code that would neededenter code here:

```
   function middle(){
   // some code;
   }
   app.get('/', middle, function (req, res) {
      console.log('url is working');
      res.send("Chat server is working!");
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your middleware function needs to have the signature: `function middle(req, res, next)`, and you need to call `next()` at the end of the middleware function so that it moves on to the next function in the chain, so based on your example the code would look like this:

```
 function middle(req, res, next){
   // some code;
   next();
 }
 app.get('/', middle, function (req, res) {
    console.log('url is working');
    res.send("Chat server is working!");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

whenever you want to make `custom middleware`,you have to invoke `next() method`.It tells the express that it has finished processing the request.If you don't invoke `next() method`,your server will `time out.`

```
 app.use((req,res,next)=> {
   //some code
    next();
});

app.get('/',(req,res)=> {
    console.log('url is working');
    res.send('chat server is working');
});
app.listen(4000);
```